# How to get the last updated time stamp of a field in field collection

Tags: entities, datetime

How to get  the last updated time stamp of a field in field collection.Is there any drupal built in function to get the timestamp

Comment: Entities have "updated" column in the database, fields and field-collecions not, so basically I think it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no timestamp for field collection items. (Drupal 7)

Answer (score 0):

To add "last updated time" on a post,
use the *Timestamp* field.
(I'm using Drupal 10)

This will not update past posts, but it will prompt the writer to select to update the stamp when editing (if you make it mandatory).

Here are the steps to implement this field (I'm using Drupal 10):

1. Structure
2. Content types
3. Select desired Content type
4. Add field
5. Select Timestamp and follow given instructions.
6. Label it "Last update" or anything you wish.

You may then rearrange where the field will show to a reader
by going to Manage display
(Structure/Content types/You content type/Manage display).